# Basic Q about head recursion in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, stack

Very basic Q as I'm very new to these concepts entirely. I put this head recursion function into Python Tutor to better understand what's going on -- why doesn't the function even touch the print('Count after recursive call:') until the VERY end? Follow up Q - why do the numbers then print in order after running through the return part of the if statement?

I feel like I'm missing something super basic here/overthinking it haha

PS. Pardon super poor formatting if it turns out that way in the post, I'm new to this lol.

```
def head_recursion(count):

    if count <= 0:

        print('Base case reached! HEAD RECURSION')

        return

    head_recursion(count-1)

    print('Count after recursive call:',count)


def main():

    print('Executing head_recursion(3)...')

    head_recursion(3)

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the recursive call must complete (reach the base case) before it can return, and until it returns, the print under it can't run.

```
def head_recursion(count):
    if count <= 0:
        print('Base case reached! HEAD RECURSION')
        return 

    # Execution gets to here, then makes a recursive call.
    # It can't continue past here until the recursive call it made returns
    head_recursion(count-1) 

    print('Count after recursive call:',count)
```

It's just like with any other code:

```
y = some_function()
print("Reached") # This won't run until some_function has returned
```

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense, didn't know that about return but figured it must have something to do with that :)